# nginx rewrite for Drupal and bad URLs

Tags: drupal, nginx, url-rewriting

This is a snippet of my nginx configuration for Drupal:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;
    root /home/testing/public_html/staging;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /backup {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        rewrite ^/staging/(.*)$ /$1;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

}
```

This works perfectly fine with URLs like these

```
http://www.testing.com/this/page
http://www.testing.com/that/page
```

until a hard-coded URL containing "/staging/" is processed. Example:

```
http://www.testing.com/staging/this/page
```

This displays the **"Page not found"** page. I tried adding this line:

```
location /staging {
    rewrite ^/staging/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
}
```

but this doesn't appear to work at all. How do I catch all URLs with "/staging/" and rewrite them properly so I don't get the "Page not found" error?

Comment: Do you mean this "/staging" part of the url is not recognize by the Drupal menu url handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `last` to trigger another round of location match. Without it, your request is trapped in the `/staging` location block.

```
location /staging {
    rewrite ^/staging/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your website configuration by trying this one.

[Here is an example of working Nginx configuration](http://phoenixdesign.fr/tutoriels/linux/migration-drupal-apache-nginx)
If it doesn't work, post your error logs.